# Filtered firebase-calls in one method, filtered by named arguments don't work -> wrong type of variable?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I tried to use the same method with a named argument to get filtered/unfiltered data from firebase.

If I declare the variable polylinesRef as final and I use only one firebase reference
without the condition/differ of the named argument "onlyOwnPolys" I get the expected correct result from firebase in "polylinesRef".

If I declare "polylinesRef" before the condition as var and I try to use it in the condition, I don't get any result.

How do I have to declare "polylinesRef" correctly? What is my mistake?

```
void _fbListenPolylines({bool onlyOwnPolys}) async {    
final currentUserUuid =
    await PrefHelper.getLoginResponse().then((r) => r.uuid);
final firebase = (await FirebaseHelper.fbDb);
var polylinesRef;
if (onlyOwnPolys == true) {
  polylinesRef = firebase
      .reference()
      .child('new_polys/$orderUuid')
      .orderByChild("userUuid")
      .startAt('$currentUserUuid')
      .endAt('$currentUserUuid');
} else {
  polylinesRef = firebase.reference().child('new_polys/$orderUuid');
}
_messagesSubscription?.cancel();

_messagesSubscription = polylinesRef.onValue
    .debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 1))
    .listen((Event event) {
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = event.snapshot.value;
  final orderSegments = map?.entries?.toList();enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator(`? :`) when declaring

```dart
final polyLineRefs = onlyOwnPolys 
    ? firebase
      .reference()
      .child('new_polys/$orderUuid')
      .orderByChild("userUuid")
      .startAt('$currentUserUuid')
      .endAt('$currentUserUuid')
    : firebase.reference().child('new_polys/$orderUuid');
```

Also, for future reference, you do not need to do boolean operation on boolean values.

✅`if (myBoolean)`

❌`if (myBoolean == true)`